# Creating Azure Recovery Service Vault - Python SDK - bad request

Tags: azure, azure-backup-vault, azure-python-sdk

I am trying to create a Recovery Service Vault in Azure using Python SDK.
**Package version: azure-mgmt-recoveryservices==2.0.0**

**Code snippet**:

```
client=RecoveryServicesClient(client_secret_credential, subscription_id)
client.vaults.begin_create_or_update(
    resource_group_name="my-custom-rg",
    vault_name="name_of_the_vault",
    vault={
        "location": "centralus", 
        "sku": {
            "name": "Standard",
        },
        "identity": {
            "type": "SystemAssigned",
        }
    }
)
```

I got the following error:

```
  File "/<my-computer-path>/azure/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/mgmt/recoveryservices/operations/_vaults_operations.py", line 293, in _create_or_update_initial
    raise HttpResponseError(response=response, error_format=ARMErrorFormat)
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: Operation returned an invalid status 'Bad Request'
```

What am I doing wrong? How could I do more "error investigation"?

Comment: You can refer to [How to Create recovery service vault using azure python SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/3031) and [azure-mgmt-recoveryservices](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/3f6238b2a224df11fa88c6501e078aac96697277/sdk/recoveryservices/azure-mgmt-recoveryservices). You can also open an issue on GitHub: [azure-sdk-for-python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT: Thank you for your help, based on the unit tests I could figure it out. However, we have a same issue and could not find any code examples, unit tests. So, I have opened an issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/21586#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10437594/robert). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

This error `azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: Operation returned an invalid status 'Bad Request'` is caused by missing `backup_policy_resource` properties.

```
policy_resource = BaseBackupPolicyResource(properties=backup_policy)
```

```
poller = client.backup_policies.create_or_update(
    vault_name="my-vault-name",
    resource_group_name="my-resource-group",
    backup_policy_name="my-daily-backup",
    parameters=policy_resource
)
```

You can refer to [How to create disk Backup Policy using azure python SDK?](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/21586#issuecomment-960984992)